# (D3.js) x-axis disappears when I set the y-axis domain to have a minimum greater than 0

Tags: javascript, d3.js, graph

**Explanation**

I have a dot plot graph which is working pretty well. However, I've been tasked with changing the y-axis so that it starts at a number closer to the minimum displayed number. Previously it was starting at 0, which meant that viewing a set of massive numbers was pretty pointless as they all looked to be on the same level.

I'm no D3 expert but I've included what I believe to be the relevant parts of the code below. I'm more than happy to include different parts if necessary.

Any idea what may be causing this?

**Code**

```
self.xMap = function (d) {
    return self.xScale(self.xValue(d));
}
self.xValue = function (d) {
    return d.x;
}
self.xScale = d3.scale.linear().range([0, width]);
self.xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(self.xScale).orient("bottom");

self.yMap = function (d) {
    return self.yScale(self.yValue(d));
}
self.yValue = function (d) {
    return d.y;
}

self.yScale = d3.scale.linear().range([height, 0])
self.yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(self.yScale).orient("left");

var svg = d3.select("div.canvas_wrapper").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

var xExtent = d3.extent(flattenedData, function (d) { return +d.x; }),
    xRange = xExtent[1] - xExtent[0];

self.xScale.domain(xValues);

var min = d3.min(flattenedData, function (ld) { return +ld.y });

/* Code that I have taken out
if (min > 0) {
    min = 0;
}*/

var yMax = d3.max(flattenedData, function (d) { return +d.y; })

var yRange = yMax - min;

self.yScale.domain([min - (yRange * .05), yMax + (yRange * .05)]);
```

**Additional Code**

I think this could be quite useful, too. It comes after the previous code.

```
var xAxisGroup = svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "x axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + (self.yScale(0)) + ")")
    .call(self.xAxis)
    .selectAll("text")
    .attr("y", 10)
    .attr("x", -10)
    .attr("dy", ".35em")
    .attr("transform", "rotate(315)")
    .style("text-anchor", "end");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem, it was this line of code.

```
.attr("transform", "translate(0," + (self.yScale(0)) + ")")
```

It was sending the x-axis down out of visible sight.

Using just the code below worked nicely.

```
.attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
```